# Disabling the undo function in word VSTO

Tags: ms-word, vsto, word-automation

I am developing a Wordaddin using visualstudio 2017 for word 2016 .i want to disable the undo when i am enabling a toggle button.

Comment: Be more specific: what do you mean by "disalbe the undo"?

Comment: A shame you didn't answer my question as there might be a way to work around your problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to repurpose the `Undo` button. See [Temporarily Repurpose Commands on the Office Fluent Ribbon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/bb462633(v=office.12)) for more information.

You can find the idMso values of built-in controls in the following documents:

- [Office 2010 Help Files: Office Fluent User Interface Control Identifiers](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6627)
- [Office 2013 Help Files: Office Fluent User Interface Control Identifiers](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36798)
- [Office 2016 Help Files: Office Fluent User Interface Control Identifiers](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50745)

Answer (score 0):

You can't disable Undo. You can try to do it using ribbon overriding but it doesn't actually work. That was true in 2010 at least, I doubt it's changed for later versions.